# CartoDB get rows in initialized map

Tags: carto

Is possible to get the data in this [example](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/blob/develop/examples/layer_selector.html)? I mean something like:

```
map = cartodb.createVis ...
map.data.each ...
```

?

Or, where in documentation can I find something about it? or, which keyword should I look for?

Answer (score 1):

The data on the map is actually in tile format. To get the raw data, you need to perform a follow-up SQL query. You can find the documentation on those methods here,

http://developers.cartodb.com/documentation/cartodb-js.html#sec-6-0